# Azure: find App Service for Role Instance

Tags: azure, azureportal

I'm trying to find the source for some log entries that I find in Application Insights.

One of the properties of these entries is the "Role Instance" (a 13 character long id).
Can I use this to find out which App Service was the source of this log entry?

Comment: Role Instance identifies the instance running the code. A web app can have multiple instances running and after a restart there might be a different instance id. Have you tried Cloud Role Name?

Comment: @PeterBons, good suggestion. Unfortunately only the Role Instance is added to the log entries in this instance, not the Role Name. (I don't know why. My knowledge in this context is rather limited, that's why I'm trying to figure out where the entries are even coming from :) )

Comment: Does the [Appliction Map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-map?tabs=net) shed some light?

Comment: Also, do you have multiple web apps pointing to the same AI resource? Can you maybe do a search using the instrumentation key to find any source code / arm / bicep template that can help identify what resource is using the AI?

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck so far... I also manually browsed through App Services, checking all their instances and comparing the IDs to the one in the log entries. Didn't find it, so still no idea what's the source. I'm a little frustrated that there seems to be no easy way to tell the Azure Portal "give me the resource that has this instance ID".

Comment: That is because the instance id maps to a for example a VM that might have been active a while ago but is replaced with another VM instance. Scale in and scale out operations for example can make that happen

Comment: Your best bet might be looking at configuration stores of the web apps to see if you can find out what instrumentation key they are configured with.

Comment: Does this help - 
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-monitor/app/resources-roles-access-control.md